# Umbraco - Disabling ASP.NET SessionState on selected pages

Tags: asp.net, session, umbraco

I have a fairly large Umbraco instance containing a mix of marketing pages and web applications.

About 10% of the Content node pages are web application pages.  I want to disable SessionState for the remaining 90% of pages which don't need it, in order to improve performance and avoid contention. We are using SQL Server sessions.

Is there any way to do this?  As far as I've been able to find out, the only way to disable SessionState on a per-page basis is to include `EnableSessionState="False"` in the .aspx `@Page` declaration. But as Umbraco generates virtual .aspx pages, I can't see any way in which to do this.

There doesn't appear to be any way in code to effect it either.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using nested webforms master pages in Umbraco (rather than MVC) you are left with one option since the Masterpages don't have the public property 'enablesessionstate'

As far as I know you are left with one option which is to handle the sessionstates in the web.config

There are two scenarios, implicit and explicit

Explicit exclusion

```
<!-- globally enbabled sessionstate -->
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="On" />
</system.web>

<!-- disable on specific paths -->
<location path="path/whatever">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="otherplace">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Implicit

```
<!-- globally disabled sessionstate -->
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<!-- enable on specific paths -->
<location path="path/whatever">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="On" />
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="otherplace">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="On" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: It seems you can't specify the `<sessionState>` element except in an application web.config - I get this error when I try this:
`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  
This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`
But as Umbraco generates the URL structure on the fly, and runs as a single application, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It depends on server policy, if the server admin doesn't allow sessionstates in the machine.config there is no solution for your problem unless you bundle a `.cs` file to your masterpages. I released a small utility for this years ago, https://umbracocs.codeplex.com/. If you do that, update any .cs file where you want to disable sesisonstate with `Page.EnableSessionstate="false"`

Comment: I've modified machine.config to allow a sessionState element within a location element, and it runs OK but unfortunately it has no effect. I've not been able to find any property in code to set it either. Thanks for the help, but it seems it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using web forms, you could potentially hook into the page loading event and check the page template to then set the session state on or off?

Which version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: Umbraco 6.2.4 - using WebForms throughout.